# How could i rewrite this query in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

```
WITH a
     AS (SELECT accen,
                accno,
                tranamt,
                COUNT(*) AS [b]
         FROM   dbo.tbl1
         WHERE  DATEt > 2 / 10 / 2013
         GROUP  BY accen,
                   accno,
                   tranamt
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
SELECT code,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   a A
       INNER JOIN dbo.tbl1 t
         ON a.accen = q.accen
            AND a.accno = t.accno
            AND a.tranamt = t.tranamt
            AND t.datet > 2 / 10 / 2013
GROUP  BY code
```

Comment: That is not how to write a date literal. `2 / 10 / 2013 = 0`. Should be `'20131002'`. Apart from that what is the purpose of the rewrite?

Comment: I agree with the date..both the above/below part come from same table so i was thinking if there is a better way to write...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of rewriting this would be

```
WITH a
     AS (SELECT *,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY accen, accno, tranamt ) AS [b]
         FROM   dbo.tbl1
         WHERE  DATEt > '20131002')
SELECT code,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   a
WHERE  b > 1
GROUP  BY code
```